# how can I group and at the same time add to fill a datagridview

Tags: linq

I want to make a LINQ that filters by IdOpval. I grouped by IdFactura and I get the sum of the unit price.

I have this table:

[image]

```
var resultGroup = from c in dm.FehabOpsFacturada
                 .Include(q => q.Factura)
                 .Include(q => q.FehabOpsValorizada)
                  where c.FehabOpsValorizada.IdValorizacion == idVal
                  group c by c.IdObra into grupo
                  select new FacturaResumen
                  {
                      IdObra = grupo.Key,
                      IdFactura = grupo.FirstOrDefault().IdFactura,
                      NombreObra = grupo.FirstOrDefault().NombreObra,
                      SerieFactura = grupo.FirstOrDefault().SerieFactura,
                      NumeroFactura = grupo.FirstOrDefault().NumeroFactura,
                      Fecha = grupo.FirstOrDefault().Fecha,
                      PesoAcumulado = grupo.Sum(x => x.Peso),
                      PrecioUnitario = grupo.FirstOrDefault().PrecioUnitario,
                      IdOpVal = grupo.FirstOrDefault().IdOpVal,
                  };
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I already solved it, I needed to put some "include".